# Delete operator runtime error in destructor

Tags: c++

I have created a class:

```
private:
    double populatie;
    double obligatii_respectate[5];
    char** intrebari;
    double** da;
    double** nu;
    int nr_intrebari;
public:
    zona1();
    void afisare(FILE*);
    void citire(FILE*);
    void citireIntrebari(int,FILE*);
    ~zona1();
};
```

Then I populated and allocated the members of the class like that:

```
#include "zona1.h"
using namespace  std;
zona1::zona1():populatie(0),intrebari(nullptr),nr_intrebari(0),da(nullptr),nu(nullptr){
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
        obligatii_respectate[i]=0;

}

void zona1::citire(FILE* input) {
    fscanf(input,"%lf",&populatie);
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
       fscanf(input,"%lf",&obligatii_respectate[i]);

}
void zona1::afisare(FILE* output) {
    fprintf(output,"Zona 1\n");
    for(int i=0; i<nr_intrebari;i++){
        double pentru=0;
        double impotriva=0;
        double prezenta_vot=0;
        fprintf(output,"%s" ,intrebari[i]);
        for(int j=0; j<5;j++){
            prezenta_vot=prezenta_vot+da[i][j];
            pentru=pentru+da[i][j]*(1-0.2*j);
        }
        for(int j=0; j<5;j++){
            prezenta_vot=prezenta_vot+nu[i][j];
            impotriva=impotriva+nu[i][j]*(1-0.2*j);
        }
         prezenta_vot=prezenta_vot*100/populatie;
        if(pentru>impotriva){
        fprintf(output,"Acceptat %0.1lf-%0.1lf\n",pentru,impotriva);

        }
        if(pentru<impotriva){
            fprintf(output,"Respins %0.1lf-%0.1lf\n",pentru,impotriva);

        }
        if(pentru==impotriva){
            fprintf(output,"Egalitate %0.1lf-%0.1lf\n",pentru,impotriva);

        }
        prezenta_vot=floor(100*prezenta_vot)/100;
        fprintf(output,"Prezenta vot: %0.2lf%\n",prezenta_vot);
    }
    }

void zona1::citireIntrebari( int nr_intrebari,FILE *input) {
    this->nr_intrebari=nr_intrebari;
    intrebari=new char*[nr_intrebari];
    da=new double*[nr_intrebari];
    nu=new double*[nr_intrebari];
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
        da[i]=new double[5];
        nu[i]=new double[5];
    }
    for(int i=0; i<nr_intrebari;i++){
        char aux[100];
        char intrebare[100];
        fgets(intrebare,100,input);
        fgets(intrebare,100,input);
        intrebari[i]= strdup(intrebare);

         fscanf(input,"%s",aux);//trec peste DA
         for(int j=0; j<5; j++) {
             fscanf(input, "%lf", &da[i][j]);

         }
        fscanf(input,"%s",aux);//trec peste NU
        for(int j=0; j<5; j++){
            fscanf(input,"%lf",&nu[i][j]);

        }
    }
}
zona1::~zona1() {
for(int i=0; i<nr_intrebari;i++)
       delete[] intrebari[i];
 delete[] intrebari;
for(int i=0; i<nr_intrebari;i++)
       delete[] da[i];
 delete[] da;
for(int i=0; i<nr_intrebari;i++)
       delete[] nu[i];
 delete[] nu;
}
```

The problem is that however I try to free the space for the dynamically allocated fields, I get a runtime error.
I know that string and vector would solve all my problems but I was forced to this in a c-like way and that's why I also used FILE* instead of ifstream...

Comment: Unless it's part of your assignment or exercise, get rid of all pointers in the `zona1` class. Use `std::vector` for your dynamic arrays, `std::array` for arrays with a size known at compile-time, and use `std::string` for all strings. Also start using the standard C++ streams for your file input.

Comment: Otherwise, if the pointers are part of your assignment or exercise, then you need to follow [the rule of three or five](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three).

Comment: Well I exactly did that and works fine, but it really makes me wonder where do I really mess it up?

Comment: Do you create copies of the `zona1` objects? Then see my second comment.

Comment: Yes, I instantiate the class in main function once.

Comment: What is your proof that `nr_intrebari` is always 5 in `zona1::citireIntrebari`? Otherwise there's going to be obvious memory corruption.

Comment: Thank you guys!! The problem was the fact that I put 5 instead of  **nr_intrebari**, I am really .....